# Website is live but ping times out

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, timeout

I have a client's website that is running on GoDaddy hosting and started behaving very strange recently. The site is up and running but when I try to ping it I get time out. The problem is PayPal doesn't work also Google Webmaster reported the site is down.

The client spoke with support and they said there is no firewall or any other traffic filter on their side. The site itself is PHP.

Any ideas are welcome.

I've tried to send test IPN from PayPal to the payment URL and got:

```
IPN delivery failed. Unable to connect to the specified URL. 
Please verify the URL and try again.
```

Which makes me think that the website/server is inaccessible in some specific cases.
The site URL is http://www.flavourly.com

P.S.: I tried to ping it from different machines, ISPs and OS

Comment: Yes, because Ping is not a web site testing tool. Most likely ICMP traffic is being blocked by a firewall. That being said, if you're troubleshooting web site problems then use web site testing tools and methods. Ping can be a Red Herring and too many people use it inappropriately and get themselves all bunched up trying to figure out why Ping doesn't work when they should be focused on the core problem, which in your case is a flaky web site.

Comment: What's the website?  Try http://host-tracker.com/ to test with as well.

Comment: OK I've used the PayPal IPN test tool to send notification to the site for a test payment and it always fails. I've updated the question.

Comment: Go to the next step. What's the URL? Test it in your browser.

Comment: The site URL is http://www.flavourly.com

Comment: The website is valid on host-tracker but pings are failing as you state, even from network-tools.com.  Suggest you get with GoDaddy support again.  (oh, and cool site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firewall at some level is blocking ICMP packets. If you don't have direct access then call support with more information e.g. host-tracker.com or ping.eu